# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath with iOS8

Tags: ios, frameworks, ios8, xcode6

I'm creating an iOS framework with Xcode6 and iOS8. When I link this with an iOS app and try running it on the device I get this error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FrameworkName.framework/FrameworkName
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0F2C2461-A68B-4ABA-A604-B88E6E9D1BB1/AppName.app/AppName
  Reason: image not found
```

The 'Runpath Search Paths' build setting for the framework is set by default to

```
'@executable_path/Frameworks', '@loader_path/Frameworks'
```

I could not find any documentation related to this. This was something new introduced with Xcode6 and I would expect it to just work by simply including the framework into any app that needs it.

Comment: You should be creating the framework as a target _in the project_ to start with. _Then_ it will "just work".

Comment: @Matt, for our use we need to keep it as another project within the same workspace. Any tips on what to do in this scenario ?

Comment: What *I* would do is this: make a new project and in that project make a new framework target. That builds and runs, so now I know what all the settings need to be for both the app target and the framework target. Now compare. :)

Comment: **Please check this answer. ** https://stackoverflow.com/a/67886532/13439617

Answer (score 80):

To make this work

1. In the framework project settings change the install directory from
   '/Library/Frameworks' to '@executable_path/../Frameworks'
2. In the project that includes this framework, add a copy files phase and copy this framework to the 'Frameworks' folder. Once you do this ensure that this framework is listed under the 'Embedded Binaries' section.

Comment: Thank you for reporting back. I believe this will be of value to others...!

Comment: Thnx, step 2 was enough for me.

Comment: I had not looked under General -> Embedded Binaries. Adding it there fixed my issue too.

Comment: Also check "Build Settings"->"Linking"->“Dynamic Library Install Name Base” is set to @rpath.

Comment: @AdamMendoza I've done same as you mentioned in my framework but i think my problem is different, so can you answer this post if you've idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50384137/library-not-loaded-issue-in-xcode#50384137

Comment: For anyone hacking around with Cordova plugins for 3rd party frameworks, step two also works if you add src/ios/Frameworks to your cordova plugin and drop your X.framework folder there. Thanks!

Comment: In case of framework as sub-xcodeproj: **We needed to change `Dynamic Library Install Name` to `$(DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME_BASE:standardizepath)/$(EXECUTABLE_PATH)`** but I had `Skip Install` set to `YES` (so, no need for Step 1), and it was already embedded in the App anyway (so, no need for Step 2 either).

Answer (score 45):

Issue resolved using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24345546/1803879). According to @vladof81:

In the target's General tab, there is an Embedded Binaries field. When you add the framework there the crash is resolved.

Reference is [here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/991384#991384) on Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: You really deserve a beer!

Comment: This fix the issue

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Please send me screensort, how i can add

Answer (score 38):

I also had same kind of problem where I was not able to launch the app & app was crashing with above message :

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FrameworkName.framework/FrameworkName Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Reason: image not found

Here is my approach that helped me to resolve this error:

1. From General Tab

> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content

- add the framework and make sure to make it **Embed & Sign**

[image: General Tab]

2. From Build Phases

> Dependences

- add the framework to it

[image: Build Phases]

Comment: I cannot add framework in Build Phased -> dependences.

Comment: Embed & Sign did the trick. I'm not sure if the second step is necessary but thank you for the answer, upvoted!

Comment: You really deserve a beer brother!! Rock the Party!! Embed & Sign did the trick, I'm not sure if the second step is necessary or not.

Answer (score 11):

Check if you can find framework in context under :

Build Phases > Embed Frameworks >

If not just add that framework in "Embed Frameworks" after adding that framework in your project directory's "Frameworks" section.
[image]

Comment: However, this is not a good solution if you have Fat frameworks because embedding the x86 slice will cause your upload to the app store to fail. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547283/submit-to-app-store-issues-unsupported-architecture-x86?rq=1

Answer (score 9):

I was getting this error on a library installed through CocoaPods. Cleaning the build folder (`cmd + option + shift + k`) and then doing a clean (`cmd + shift + k`) was what ended up resolving this issue for me.

Comment: Same here! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Carthage

Run `carthage update` on terminal

Go to Project Settings -> Build Phases -> Carthage Copy Frameworks

Add line in **Inputs files**:
`$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/YOURLIBRARY.framework`

Add this line to **Output files:**
`$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH)/YOURLIBRARY.framework`

Answer (score 4):

Made the library which shows not loaded changed from **required to optional in Linked binaries and frameworks.** It is working perfectly now

Answer (score 3):

For me it was because of the SSL issue, I had set my developer, distribution certificates on my Mac(Keychain) to 'Always Trust' for one of my other project. I had to change them back to 'Use System Defaults'. it was working for me then!!

Answer (score 2):

I also had same kind of problem where I was not able to launch the app & app was crashing with above message :

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FrameworkName.framework/FrameworkName
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Reason: image not found

Here is my approach that helped me to resolve this error:

1.Please delete your app from device, Clean the build and and rebuild and run on the device.

2.If above steps does not help you, then please check for below settings :
From "TARGET">"Build Settings">"Runpath Search Paths" & then check for values "$(inherited)" & "@executable_path/Frameworks", Feel free to add incase they don't exist.

Build your app and run it on device

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above solutions, recheck the paths of frameworks included in your application under

**Build Settings --> Search Paths --> Framework Search Paths**

Answer (score 1):

**When non of those solution works:**

1. (Optional) Get a clear knowledge from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8343878/1084174) on different search path type
2. Make sure that your `.framework` file paths are added in `Build Settings -> Framework Search Paths`. You can keep all framework files somewhere in `App/libs/` and add this folder and enable recursively.
3. Make sure that your `.a` files paths are added in `Build Settings -> Library Search Paths`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I installed third party libraries using Cocoapods. Got the same error, tried everything but finally realised I havent had use_frameworks! in my pod file.

So removed the currently installed library, added use_frameworks! line in pod file, reinstalled the libraries and all worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The way tested by me is well.

In "Linked Binary With Libraries" change the missing framework to "Embedded Framework".

Because, "Do not Embedded" do not copy to the App, but Embedded Framework will copy into it.