# Xcode build fails for an app created through flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I have a flutter project and I'm trying to generate an iOS build using Xcode. When I try to generate the build ( on a iPhone 14 simulator) and running Xcode 14.2, I run into the following error.

```
dyld[45967]: Library not loaded: @rpath/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension.framework/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension
  Referenced from: <C12ED307-66B2-31CA-AD51-7EF5E2C4AB60> /Users/vinis/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/04461EDE-0C7F-4395-95F7-037A0AAF04A1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/966582AA-6027-4ABD-963A-6AD02C9020E4/Runner.app/Runner
  Reason: tried: '/Users/vinis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cbqvodlpazavvrfpsneetzdsikcz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension.framework/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension' (errno=2), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension.framework/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension.framework/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension.framework/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension.framework/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/Users/vinis/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/04461EDE-0C7F-4395-95F7-037A0AAF04A1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/966582AA-6027-4ABD-963A-6AD02C9020E4/Runner.app/Frameworks/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension.framework/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension' (errno=2), '/Users/vinis/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/04461EDE-0C7F-4395-95F7-037A0AAF04A1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/966582AA-6027-4ABD-963A-6AD02C9020E4/Runner.app/Frameworks/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension.framework/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension' (errno=2), '/Users/vinis/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/04461EDE-0C7F-4395-95F7-037A0AAF04A1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/966582AA-6027-4ABD-963A-6AD02C9020E4/Runner.app/Frameworks/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension.framework/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension' (errno=2), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension.framework/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension.framework/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension.framework/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension.framework/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/Users/vinis/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/04461EDE-0C7F-4395-95F7-037A0AAF04A1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/966582AA-6027-4ABD-963A-6AD02C9020E4/Runner.app/Frameworks/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension.framework/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension' (errno=2), '/Users/vinis/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/04461EDE-0C7F-4395-95F7-037A0AAF04A1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/966582AA-6027-4ABD-963A-6AD02C9020E4/Runner.app/Frameworks/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension.framework/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension' (errno=2), '/Users/vinis/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/04461EDE-0C7F-4395-95F7-037A0AAF04A1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/966582AA-6027-4ABD-963A-6AD02C9020E4/Runner.app/Frameworks/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension.framework/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension' (errno=2), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension.framework/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension' (errno=2)
Library not loaded: @rpath/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension.framework/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension
  Referenced from: <C12ED307-66B2-31CA-AD51-7EF5E2C4AB60> /Users/vinis/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/04461EDE-0C7F-4395-95F7-037A0AAF04A1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/966582AA-6027-4ABD-963A-6AD02C9020E4/Runner.app/Runner
  Reason: tried: '/Users/vinis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cbqvodlpazavvrfpsneetzdsikcz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension.framework/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension' (errno=2), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension.framework/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension.framework/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simrunt
dyld config: DYLD_SHARED_CACHE_DIR=/Users/vinis/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches/dyld/22D68/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-2.20C52 DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/vinis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cbqvodlpazavvrfpsneetzdsikcz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/usr/lib/libRPAC.dylib:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/vinis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cbqvodlpazavvrfpsneetzdsikcz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib
(lldb)
```

I have tried [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244468/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-with-ios8) options for resolving this error but none of them worked, and I'd appreciate any insights on this.

Thanks!

I have tried the following:
From General Tab
Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content
add the framework and make sure to make it Embed & Sign

But it didn't work.

I also tried running a clean build and trying it again.