# dyld[85946]: Library not loaded: @rpath/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, swiftui, google-signin

I am working on an iOS application in which I have use the google sign. By adding google Sign, AppAuth module is also added into my project.

Now my project compiles without any error but once the app launches it give me this error.
`'/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/qaziammar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cold_Therapy_swiftUI-gyudorvasbgwplgytwphqhodmuxw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file), '/System/Library/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file, not in dyld cache)`

I tired different solution but nothing work for me.

1. [iOS app with framework crashed on device, dyld: Library not loaded, Xcode 6 Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333981/ios-app-with-framework-crashed-on-device-dyld-library-not-loaded-xcode-6-beta)

[image: Console error]

I have followed [Authenticate Using Google Sign-In on Apple Platforms](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin) and add it through CocoaPods. Here is my Podfile:

```
target 'Cold Therapy swiftUI' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  
  pod 'FSCalendar'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn', '6.0.0'
  pod 'SwiftLint'

  target 'Cold Therapy swiftUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'Cold Therapy swiftUIUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
          project.targets.each do |target|
              target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                  config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
               end
          end
   end
end
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath with iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244468/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-with-ios8)

Comment: Not sure there's enough info in the question to help. *How* are your libraries added? Podfile? SPM? Did you follow this guide [Authenticate Using Google Sign-In on Apple Platforms](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin) to set up Google Sign-In in your project? If so, did you go through it again to ensure a step was not overlooked? Do you use CocoaPods? What version? What's the podfile look like (hint: include it in the question). Update your question with details and we'll take a look.

Comment: @Jay Question updated, please let me know if you need further information.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but is this a typo: `swiftUIUITests` ?

Comment: If your adding Auth via the guide linked in the question, the podfile looks incomplete. The podfile should have other pods and the app should import FirebaseCore, FirebaseAuth and then GoogleSignIn as well. See [Install Firebase with Cocoapods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/installation-methods#cocoapods). Is that the case?